# Publishing app - Limiting by device in Android Market

Tags: java, android, google-play

I'm about to publish my Android application on the marketplace, however I've decided to just design it for devices with normal screen sizes and with high density (The HTC Desire for example).

This application will not look right on any other device apart from those with the same spec as the HTC Desire.

I was wondering how I might be able to limit the application on the market to fit these specifications?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package=""
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

            <supports-screens 
                  android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens= "false"
                  android:anyDensity="false"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="480"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="480"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <activity android:name=".PhonegapScreenshotPluginActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a  manifest element, which can be of more use in your situation. Here's a [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) to the documentation page. In Manifest it will look like this:

```
   <compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
   </compatible-screens>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah this is it. I had to up the SDK version to 9 but it was worth it.

Answer (score 6):

If your application is for Android 3.2 and higher, you can use :

```
                 <supports-screens 
                  android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens= "false"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="480"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="480"/>
```

else you can use :

```
                 <supports-screens 
                  android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens= "false"
                  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Have a look at the following urls:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Also I would like to share with you following text:

What does it mean when we say normal screen?

> We tell Android that we only support devices that fall into the normal
>   screens class. Note that this doesn’t necessarily imply that our
>   application isn’t installable anymore on other devices. It doesn’t
>   even mean that it’s doomed to break on them, but it has other
>   implications. We didn’t mention actual sizes in pixels or densities in
>   dpi.

For more details, please read page 146 of 
http://www.manning.com/collins/AiP_sample_ch04.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply, these are the options I have available in my manifest file: http://i.imgur.com/EzyX1.png. Is this correct?

Comment: Ok, apparently it does not limit to normal size, high density devices. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have edited the above code to suit your requirement exactly. Just copy and paste it in your manifest file over your old support-screen tag.

Comment: Thanks, although i'm now getting: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'largestWidthLimitDp' in package 'android'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'requiresSmallestWidthDp' in package 
  'android'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'compatibleWidthLimitDp' in package 
  'android'